# How to call method before all public methods in PHP?

Tags: php, class

I need a method which will run before each my public method.

Is there a method like __call for public methods?

I want to trim all arguments before my setter methods.

Comment: An other mehtod you do call before you all public call any methods?

Comment: I want to trim all arguments in setter methods

Comment: PHP does not have before- and after-filter functionality like some other languages. Some PHP frameworks offer this feature, but in their absence you would have to use wrapper methods to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @imsiso no I need more flexible solution because I have many setter methods

Comment: @imsiso I know these methods but they don't do what I need.

Comment: sorry my Internet and also my English is bad so please help me help you.(-:

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no mechanism like `__call` for public methods. But `__call()` is already what you are looking for.

I would define a "pseudo public" interface using `__call`:

```
class A {

    protected $value;

    /**
     * Enables caller to call a defined set of protected setters.
     * In this case just "setValue".
     */
    public function __call($name, $args) {
        // Simplified code, for brevity 
        if($name === "setValue") {
            $propertyName = str_replace("set", "", $name);
        }

        // The desired method that should be called before the setter
        $value = $this->doSomethingWith($propertyName, $args[0]);

        // Call *real* setter, which is protected
        $this->{"set$propertyName"}($value);
    }

    /**
     * *Real*, protected setter
     */
    protected function setValue($val) {
        // What about validate($val); ? ;)
        $this->value = $val;
    }

    /**
     * The method that should be called
     */
    protected function doSomethingWith($name, $value) {
         echo "Attempting to set " . lcfirst($name) . " to $value";
         return trim($value);
    }
}
```

If you try the example:

```
$a = new A();
$a->setValue("foo");
```

... you'll get the following output:

```
Attempting to set value to foo
```

Comment: __call does not work for the parent class public method as it expects everything private.